# What is the difference? "being that nasty" vs "was nasty"

Tags: past-simple

Would you please to explain the difference?

> Even with the weather **being that nasty**, the couple and their families
>   decided to go ahead with the wedding as planned.
>
> Even though the weather **was nasty**, the couple and their families
>   decided to go ahead with the wedding as planned.

The first form is very unusual for me, because it uses "ing"(I mean "being") in past simple sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence contains "the weather being that nasty", which is a [participle clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/participle-clauses).

"even with" functions like "in spite of": here are some [examples](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/in-spite-of-and-despite) that use a participle clause with "in spite of" and "despite":

> He was very fast in spite of **being terribly overweight**.
>
> They arrived late despite **leaving in plenty of time**.

Note that, in the second example, as in your first sentence, the participle clause appears to be in present tense despite referring to an event in the past.

The use of a participle clause is just a matter of literary style: it would be much simpler without.

> Despite the nasty weather, the couple and their families decided to go ahead with the wedding as planned.

Comment: Maybe "leaving *with* plenty of time"?

Comment: @Peter, these are direct quotes from the linked sorce. Anyway, when talking about being early for an appointment, **in plenty of time** is the idiomatic expression, in the same way as **in time for the meeting** indicates puncuality whereas **with time for the meeting** does not.